# How to redirect to the form with entered data if a form content have any error in magento 2 admin custom form?

Tags: custom, adminform, admin-controller, redirect-url, magento2.4.5p1

I have a custom admin form, After click save button i am checking some unique url in my save controller. If the url is not unique, i want to pass an error message and redirected to the form with filed data. I tried to set referer url and its redirecting but my form data is cleared. Code part of my save controller. This is redirecting to the form but form data is cleared.

```
if (count($catData)!=0 && $faqCatId=='') {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("Url Key Already Exist.");
        $path = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to save the entered data of form content you need to use Session or functionality to achieve this.

Magento use Sessions to sort and store temporarily variables on the page. Example is:

```
 public function getFormData()
{
    $data = $this->getData('form_data');
    if ($data === null) {
        $formData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerFormData(true);
        $data = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        if ($formData) {
            $data->addData($formData);
            $data->setCustomerData(1);
        }
        if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
            $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
        }
        $this->setData('form_data', $data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```